# relations issue with laravel

Tags: laravel, has-many

I am trying to make games website, so i have one-to-many relation: one category has many games.

in my db, I have games' table and cats' table.

in the games' table I have a column named as 'cat_game_id' which reffers to the category's id, that the game belongs to.

my 'game' model looks like this

`
class Game extends Model {

```
protected $fillable = array(
    'name',
    'slug',
    'description',
    'instruction',
    'url',
    'cat_game_id',
    'created_at',
    'updated_at'
);

/*
 * A game belongs to a category
 */
public function cat() {

    return $this->belongsTo('App\catGame');
}
```

}
`

and i have another model called 'catGame':

`class catGame extends \Eloquent {

```
public $timestamps = false;

protected $fillable = array(
    'name',
    'location',
    'slug'
);

/*
 * A category has many games
 */
public function games() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Game');
}
```

}
`

In my index page I want to show the game's name, and next to it the category's name. so I did: 

`$view->game = Game::where('slug', '=', $slug)->firstOrFail();
$view->cat_name = $view->game->cat->name;`

but I get this error:
`Trying to get property of non-object`

any ideas please?

Comment: the tables in my db are: 'games', 'cat_games'. both had id column, and as I said, games' table had a culomn named 'cat_game_id'

Comment: `cat_game_id` does not follow the convention, so, I think, you should add the second argument: `return $this->belongsTo('App\catGame', 'cat_game_id`);`